# Need to find the version of IE browser using Watir

Tags: watir

Is it possible to find the IE version through WATIR Code? I need to know the opened browser is IE11 or IE10 or IE9 or IE8? Is it possible to know this result by WATIR code?

Comment: Why would you want to know which browser you are using? I would think that you control that in CI.

Comment: what is this CI? Where can I access this?

Comment: CI is continuous integration. Its where the software is built, unit tests are run, and rspec/cucumber tests run everytime somebody checks code into the branch. It's a good practice to have it. Wherever you run the tests,  it's a good idea to have control over the system the tests are run on. If you are not running software tests, disregard my comments.

Comment: hi, thanks, Yes, I do run test cases. Can you tell me where can I access Or how can I use this?

Comment: CI is a big topic. MFowler has a good description at http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html . You have to integrate your source control (git, svn, cvs, etc.) to a build server (jenkins, hudson, cruise control, etc.) by implementing the build (mvn, ant, buildr, etc.). If you must use IE, then you set up a windows test server that runs the browser. Otherwise you can test it headless (without a viewable interface, like it's in the dark). There is a lot to cover in a SO comment so you should research the topic.

Comment: hi, Thank you, I would do research on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution will depend on if you are using Watir-Webdriver or Watir-Classic.

**Watir-Webdriver**

The version can be retrieved from the driver capabilities:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ie
p browser.driver.capabilities[:version]
#=> "8"
```

**Watir-Classic**

The version is retrieved from the registery using:

```
require 'watir-classic'
p Watir::Browser.version
#=> "8.0.7601.17514"
```

Comment: hi, Watir::Browser.version is not working for me, it throws the error that version is undefined function, But Watir::IE.version is working for me. But I am using IE 11, but it prints the output "9.11.9600.17501", It would have to start with 11, Isn't it?

Comment: What version of Watir-Classic are you using? In the current version of Watir-Classic, Watir::IE should be an alias for Watir::Browser. However, Watir::IE is being deprecated and so there would be a warning.

Comment: OK, I am using watir-classic 3.0.0

Comment: It looks like a bug in version 3.0.0 that was fixed in a later release. In other words, if I use version 3.0.0 I get the same version "9.11" but if I use the latest version (4.0.1) I get the expected "11.0". Your options appear to be upgrade to a more recent version or back port the method from 4.0.1.